# What do the x2, x3, x4 numbers by killed bad guys in LEGO Batman mean?

Tags: lego-batman

In LEGO Batman (PC version in case that matters) there are little x2, x3, x4 that appear next to the hordes of bad guys as you kill them.  What do they mean?

Comment: is it not just a combo counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are combo multipliers that you get for defeating successive enemies quickly.  While the multipliers are active, you gain that bonus for all studs you collect.  If you are able to quickly defeat a number of enemies in an area with a lot of studs, you can greatly increase the amount of studs you have collected.